# The jprofiler_linux_14_0.rpm file is not compatible with ppc64le

Tags: jprofiler

### What is the issue?

The Linux RPM in https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/jprofiler/files does not support PowerPC64 LE though the site stated that it does.

### How to re-produce?

1. Go to https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/jprofiler/files
2. Go to Linux section, then choose RPM (105MB) link to download the file
3. Try to install that file with `rpm -i jprofiler_linux_14_0.rpm`

### Expected

No error with installation

### Actual

package jprofiler-14.0-1.i386 is intended for a different architecture

### More info

file /home/tle/Downloads/jprofiler_linux_14_0.rpm
/home/tle/Downloads/jprofiler_linux_14_0.rpm: RPM v3.0 bin i386/x86_64 jprofiler_linux_14_0.rpm

So where is the link to the ppc64le RPM file? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of JProfiler 14.0, the architecture of the RPM is indeed set to i386, although it contains binaries for several Linux architectures. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a download link for a beta build of 14.0.1 where this is fixed.